# Same name tables under different schemas with SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms, sql-server-2005-express

I know how to create a new schema and write a DDL script to create tables with the same name that reside in different schemas in the same database. I want to know how to do that using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express.

To repeat, I want to know if I can create two tables having the same name but residing in different schemas of the same database using SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do that by changing the schema property in property window to a different value than `dbo` (which is the default value of schema) for the new table being created in SQL Server.

While you in the process of creating a new table in your database press `F4` key and properties window will be shown on the right hand side of your screen. That properties window shows the various attributes of the new table being created:

[image]

You can choose any of the built-in schemas e.g. `guest`,`db_owner` etc. from the drop down box or your own custom schema which you are using in your database.

To answer your original question - As long as you are setting the schema property of the two tables you are creating to a unique value (e.g. `dbo`, `guest`) even if they have same name let's say `table1` it should not cause any problem.